# How can I have different versions of an API in backstage.io?

Tags: swagger, openapi, backstage

I have a "petstore service" (backend) that provides a "petstore api" (rest).

In backstage.io, service and api are separated entities with a relationship (one provides another).

This works just fine, but I have a new requirement: I need to have different versions of the API depending on the environment we are talking about {dev, qa, production}.

Right now, what I am doing is creating one "petstore service" and several "petstore api", one for each environment

Although this can work, it has a side effect of not working very well with our git repo: I need to have several openapi-{dev,qa}.yml files that may be confusing with git branches.

Is there a better way to solve these requirements?